# Is is possible to use the same variables and checks in multiple prepared statements in PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am still trying to convert mysql_* things into PDO and prepared statements. It is really hard work to do this in entire web but I am not giving up and I ran into some problems.

My question is about multiple `mysql_query()` commands in one function. So when i have something like this in code:

```
if (something)
{
   mysql_query("UPDATE account SET pass=$pass WHERE id=$id");
   mysql_query("UPDATE account_2 SET lock=$lock WHERE id=$id");
   mysql_query("UPDATE account_3 SET surname=$surname WHERE id=$id");                      
}
```

And want to tranfer it to PDO an prepared statements. I already know I have to do something like this:

```
if (something)
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE account SET pass=:pass WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt->bindValue(':pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();                      
}
```

I have actually two questions:
Is it ok to bindValue password as string (PDO::PARAM_STR)?
When I add other statements as it has more queries should I name them differently like $stmt2 or when it is executed I can do only $stmt all the time like this?

```
if (something)
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE account SET pass=:pass WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt->bindValue(':pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE account_2 SET lock=:lock WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt->bindValue(':lock', $lock, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();                      
}
```

Or should I rather do this?

```
if (something)
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE account SET pass=:pass WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt->bindValue(':pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt2 = $db->prepare("UPDATE account_2 SET lock=:lock WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt2->bindValue(':lock', $lock, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt2->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt2->execute();                      
}
```

And one more at the end. When I have in code function/check like this:

```
if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO account (id, pass, email, request_time, status) VALUES ('".$id."', '".$pass."', '".$mail."', '".time()."', '".$status."')"))
{
    blabla
}
```

How to use suck check in stmt and PDO if the insert command was executed if it needs to be there in PDO in the first place?

And last question ... when I already bindValue in prepared statement in PDO do I later in code still need to use is_numeric() function?

So Summary:

1) Is it ok to bindValue password as string (PDO::PARAM_STR)?

2) When I add statements as it has more queries should I name them differently like $stmt, $stmt2, $stmt3 or every statement the same?

3) When I already bindValue in prepared statement in PDO do I later in code still need to use is_numeric() function (maybe for some cheating with the variable)?

Thank you all

Comment: `Is it ok to bindValue password as string (PDO::PARAM_STR)?` - what else could it be? Integer? :)

Comment: Why not just do it in 1 query?

Comment: @N.B. Yes YOu are right just panicked if this is really ok or if this has some special binding value as it is password.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Because I am changing tables this is just an example it is not always in account table i use multiple tables in these querries :)

Comment: Well, your database doesn't have any special "password" data types, it's probably a textual field (varchar, text etc.) that you use to store passwords. You don't have many options between PDO::PARAM_STR and PDO::PARAM_INT (I'm deliberately not mentioning INOUT parameters because you probably won't need them yet).

Comment: @N.B. Ok so I will not ask what it is when I do not need it thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes
2. you can name them `$stmt` because you won't need a different one (once you execute you are done, so you can overwrite if you want to). But What I don't get is why dont you just place it all in 1 statement in stead of 3 different ones?
3. Don't really get what you mean here? If you need to know if it's numeric you will need is_numeric() yeah.

And you can check if it was executed succesfully with `$stmt->execute();` because it returns true if succesfull.

So you would do

```
$passed = $stmt->execute();

if($passed)
{
    //fetch
}
```

Here's a simple example:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `account`
                         SET account.pass = ?
                       WHERE account.id = ?
                       LIMIT 1");

$stmt->bindParam(1, $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($stmt->execute())
{
    $stmt->fetch(); //fetch your data
}
else
{
    //error
}
```

Comment: OK i edited the question to have multiple table names as it was just example and tables are different thats why multiple statements :) Thx

Comment: You can also make PDO throw exceptions on errors and you can have a nice error handling system with PDO and try/catch blocks.

Comment: Can you make an example in my prepared statement I posted above in you answer? :) Thx

Comment: @Byakugan Added example for your prepared statement. Good luck ;)

Comment: @Bono can you extend it with error report which made Brook Julias in his anwer to be in one answer and I can accept it? :) Also I like nameing variables instead of numbers when there are a lot of them so to be sure and get it clear in code what is what :) Thx

Comment: @Byakugan Why not combine them together yourself? You'll learn more ;) + It would be a lame move to copy his code in to my answer ;)

Comment: I meant to be in one place on concrete example I am unable to edit your answer :)

Comment: @Byakugan His code is very different from mine too. Really it shouldnt be too hard to manage yourself ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do it in 1 query like so:

```
<?php
if (something){
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE account SET pass=:pass, lock=:lock, surname=:surname WHERE id=:id");

    $stmt->bindValue(':pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':lock', $lock, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':surname', $surname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

}
?>
```

You can alternatively make a function that will handle all your updates, then you only need pass an array of values and the function is reusable throughout your script, why repeat code for every update query when you can call a single function.

```
<?php
/**
 * Update multiple rows
 *
 * @param string $table
 * @param array $values
 * @param sring $pk
 * @param int $id
 */
function Update($table, $values){
    //connect ect here

    $fieldnames = array_keys($values[0]);
    $fields = '';
    foreach($fieldnames as $keys){
        //continue as id, id is used in the WHERE clause
        if($keys=='id'){continue;}

        $fields .= $keys.'=:'.$keys.', ';
    }
    $fields = trim($fields,', ');

    /*** put the query together ***/
    $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$fields} WHERE id=:id";

    /*** prepare and execute $db being your PDO connection object ***/
    $statement = $db->prepare($sql);

    foreach($values as $vals){
        $statement->execute($vals);
    }
}

$updates = array(array('id'=>1,'pass'=>'password1','lock'=>1,'surname'=>'Foo'),
                 array('id'=>2,'pass'=>'password2','lock'=>2,'surname'=>'Bar'),
                 array('id'=>3,'pass'=>'password3','lock'=>3,'surname'=>'Cherone'));

Update('account', $updates);
?>
```

Comment: I added more tables as they should be thats is why not use single update statement it was just an example with mutiple tables of course :) I am using variable update queries, indert, delete ... I will stay in my way of doing it instead of this "general* one, but thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(something){
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE account SET pass=:pass WHERE id=:id");
    try{
        $flag = $stmt->execute(array(":pass"=>$pass,":id"=>$id));
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        do something;
    }

    if(!(bool)$flag){
        $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
        do something;
    }

    $stmt2 = $db->prepare("UPDATE account_2 SET lock=:lock WHERE id=:id");
    try{
        $flag2 = $stmt->execute(array(":lock"=>$lock,":id"=>$id));
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        do something;
    }

    if(!(bool)$flag2){
        $errorInfo = $stmt2->errorInfo();
        do something;
    }
}

$query0 = "INSERT INTO account (id, pass, email, request_time, status) VALUES (:id,:pass,:mail,:time,:status)";
$pQuery0 = $db->prepare($query)

try{
    $flag0 = $stmt->execute(array(":pass"=>$pass,":id"=>$id,":mail"=>$mail,":time"=>$time,":status"=>$status));
}catch(PDOException $e){
    do something;
}   

if((bool)$flag2){
    do something
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between putting query in separate variable instead do it in prepare() is it safer of just visual?

Comment: Can you make an example exactly in my prepared statement I posted above?

Comment: I will work on an example for you. I'm not sure as to the difference.